# Cannot login after routine software update 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, login

I did some (i thought routine) updates.
Now I cannot login from the GUI, also the resolution of the login screen is messed up (I have a new NVIDIA card).
I searched and tried the options.
Changed recursively the permission on my home directory. 
Removed .Xauthority. 
Reinstalled xorg.
Removed /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you install an Nvidia driver from .run file?